# How does one retrieve an arbritrary user's ssh public keys from GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

How does one retrieve an arbritrary user's ssh public keys from GitLab?

GitHub provides this feature. For example: https://github.com/winny-.keys

The [GitLab API exposes public keys](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#list-ssh-keys-for-user), however it looks like it requires:

1. Separate authentication
2. Query a given user name for its UID
3. Finally get the public keys

Answer (score 38, accepted):

GitHub style ssh public key access [was added in GitLab 6.6.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/071ae261/CHANGELOG#L1110) using the following scheme: `http://__HOST__/__USERNAME__.keys` (thanks @bastelflp).

Currently we are running 6.2.3, and we will upgrade.

Comment: From the docu: Retrieving user ssh keys from GitLab publically(github style): `http://__HOST__/__USERNAME__.keys`

Comment: @bastelflp promote your comment to an answer, and you shall get some votes ;)

Comment: I'll add it to my answer for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

You also have, with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#new-api-endpoints-for-keys-and-tokens) (March 2022):

> ### New API endpoints for keys and tokens
>
> GitLab 14.9 delivers new REST API endpoints:
>
> - Return a single SSH key for a specified user. This is useful to enable GitLab SSH keys to be a
>   [Terraform-managed resource](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/#the-gitlab-terraform-provider).
> - Return a single project’s deploy token by ID. This allows for a simple request to return a deploy token instead of
>   returning and sorting through pages deploy tokens with the API.
> - Return a single group access token or project access token.
>
> Thank you [Timo Furrer](https://gitlab.com/tuxtimo) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html), [Issue 354889](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/354889), [Issue 355778](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/355778) and [Issue 355893](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/355893).

[Example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#single-ssh-key-for-given-user):

```
GET /users/:id/keys/:key_id
```

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Public key",
  "key": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAiPWx6WM4lhHNedGfBpPJNPpZ7yKu+dnn1SJejgt4596k6YjzGGphH2TUxwKzxcKDKKezwkpfnxPkSMkuEspGRt/aZZ9wa++Oi7Qkr8prgHc4soW6NUlfDzpvZK2H5E7eQaSeP3SAwGmQKUFHCddNaP0L+hM7zhFNzjFvpaMgJw0=",
  "created_at": "2014-08-01T14:47:39.080Z"
}
```

---

And See [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#deploy-keys-by-user-api) (June 2022) adds:

> ### Deploy keys by user API
>
> Previously, to enable deploy keys for a group of projects, administrator access was required to retrieve the `id` of the deploy key.
>
> This release adds a new API endpoint (`GET /users/:id_or_username/project_deploy_keys`) to retrieve all the keys accessible by a given user, so you can complete this task without waiting for an administrator.
>
> In a future [iteration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/365466), the API will also include public deploy keys.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deploy_keys.html#list-project-deploy-keys-for-user) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28766).